# Showing div using anchor in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, toggle

I am using the [jQuery-collapse plugin](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Collapse) to hide/show the body content of posts, and want each post to also be accessible by URL.

```
<div id="<?php the_slug(); ?>" data-collapse>
   <div id="collapse">

        //  Toggle content

   </div>


   <div class="main-content">

        // Hidden content       

   </div>
</div>
```

The method I am trying is to call the post slug as the post ID (so I can use #the_slug in the url), find it, and then give the first child of the collapser the class "open" (which the plugin should recognise). As follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash != "") {
    var id = hash.substr(1);
    var d = document.getElementById(id);
    d.firstChild.className = "open";
} 
};
```

It does work insofar as the class is applied to the first child, but the plugin doesn't acknowledge it (it does if I add `class="open"` to the markup).

Any help in understanding why / other options much appreciated.

Comment: you are including jQuery, right? I see you're writing plain js above.

Comment: yes, am including jQuery, but don't know it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the lib does not listen to classname changes.

Fron the API of the plugin

```
$(d).children( ).eq(0).trigger("open");
```

Use this code instead of className assignment.

Comment: In the end I used `$(d).first().trigger("open")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `jQuery`, you can do:

```
if(hash != "") {
    $(hash).addClass("open");
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, I probably should do it in jQuery. but the problem is getting the plugin to acknowledge the change of class, or to find another way to trigger the toggling.